# What about a sentence.like ...I like going to "new" places with "old" friends---

Tags: phrases

What can we call the above 
I ENJOY GOING TO "NEW" PLACES WITH "OLD" FRIENDS
and can you think of other examples?

Comment: What are you asking about?  The scare quotes?

Comment: Hi, Kmk, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Because asking for examples makes for an open-ended question, this site tends to view such questions as off-topic. But a more immediate problem with your question is that it's very difficult to interpret. Are you asking what the rhetorical strategy of juxtaposing phrases that have opposite tendencies—such as "new places" with "old friends" in your example sentence—is called? Or do you have some other question in mind? Please clarify what you're looking for here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would just refer to it as juxtaposition, I think? I don't know that there's a particularly easy way to refer to the contrasting of opposite words like these ones.

Comment: The usual term, both in the precise rhetorical sense (see http://literarydevices.net/antithesis/) and the muddier common use, is 'antithesis'.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the word 'aphorism'. There are entire books of aphorisms, online and off, and so no need to think of examples. As an example of such a book, consider [**Aphorisms**](http://classics.mit.edu/Hippocrates/aphorisms.1.i.html), by Hippocrates. Often, aphorisms become cliches, and in the process lose their meaning. Exploiting this circumstance can deliver rhetorical and humorous profits:

"You must be the change you want to find in your pocket."

Comment: I don't think so.  An aphorism is a pithy statement that teaches a lesson of general truth:  "A stitch in time saves nine."  The statement given is just a declaration of liking to go some places with some people.  It has no instructive purpose.

Comment: You're quite right that the sentence can be construed as a simple declaration, however (and you knew there'd be a 'however', right?), given that the declaration is couched in a more-or-less classical antithesis, my guess as to the intention of the utterance was that the speaker meant to express, adopting your definition, 'a pithy truth' concerning the speaker's 'general' inclinations.

Comment: Your mind-reading capabilities are better than mine.

Comment: "I am the owner of my shoulders, the tenant of my hips." -- Chazal, from *The Viking Book of Aphorisms* (1962, p. 5), by W.H. Auden and Louis Kronenberger.